# Can not reload my home state in tree detailview application

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am having a problem trying to reload a part of my angular page
I have a tree on my home state and a detailview on my entities state.
Whenever I update my detail view I want to reload my tree.

what I have tried is to do

```
$state.reload()
```

when I was on state `app.home.entity.standard-fact-code-detail`
thinking that that would reload the entire tree also.

after that I tried:

```
$state.go('home', {}, { reload: true });
```

but I am getting `cannot load abstract state`

any help would be much appreciated

the state hierarchy is as follows:

```
app (abstract) 
    home  (tree is in the template of this state)
       entity (abstract)
           entity1 (views: 'entities@home') (parameter: id)
           entity2 (views: 'entities@home') (parameter: id)
           entity3 (views: 'entities@home') (parameter: id)
```

my home state is as follows:

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
            parent: 'app',
            url: '/',
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html',
                    controller: 'HomeController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            }
        });
```

home.html

```
<div ng-cloak>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>TreeExplorer</h1>
            <div id="treeDiv" class="col-md-4 blue-well well">

               //my tree 

                 <node class="noselect" data="treeItems.factCodes" toggle="treeItems.factCodesToggle" title="treeItems.nodeName" child="true"></node>

            </div>
              // my details page

            <div class="col-md-8 well" ui-view="entities">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then the entity state:

```
$stateProvider.state('entity', {
            abstract: true,
            parent: 'home'
        });
```

and state of a random entity (all are similar) :

```
.state('standard-fact-code-detail', {
            parent: 'entity',
            url: '/standard-fact-code/{id}',
          views: {
                'entities@home': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/entities/standard-fact-code/standard-fact-code-detail.html',
                    controller: 'StandardFactCodeDetailController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can use $window to reload your page

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $state, $window) {
  $window.$location.reload();
  $state.go('home');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it myself. Apparently there was a different state change in progress which silently gave an exception when trying to transition to reloading the home state.

By wrapping in $timeout I was able to make sure that the transition only happened when this state transition had finished.

```
$scope.$on('tree-update', function(event, data) {
            $timeout(function(){
                $state.reload();
            });
        });
```